# Error filtering lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe

Normally, one filters a pandas Dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(...)
df_filtered = df[df['column'] == value]
```

I have the following dataframe `df1`:

```
numbers    letters   other_columns
0          [A]     ....
1          [A]     ....
2          [C]     ....
3          [B]     ....
4          [B]     ....
5          [A]     ....
...        ....
```

I thought that the entries in `letters` were strings, but these are actually lists:

```
type(df1.letters.ix[0])
```

outputs `list`

So, I tried to filter the dataframe `df1` to only have `[A]` rows.

That is `only_A` should look like:

```
numbers    letters   other_columns
0          [A]     ....
1          [A]     ....
5          [A]     ....
...        ....
```

However, if I try to filter with the code

```
only_A = df1[df1['letters'] == list('A')]
```

I get an error, a `ValueError`

```
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 3076 vs 1
```

What is the correct way to filter this dataframe?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: If you thought the contents of letters were strings, could you convert the column of lists to strings?  something like this:  df['letters'] = df['letters'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))  Then proceed to filter like you normally would.

Comment: Do you require lists for that Series?  If not, you could unpack the letters and then do a normal filter on the letter in question.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan See edit above. It's a ValueError

Comment: @flyingmeatball So far, this does indeed work. That might be the correct answer in this scenario; however, there may be other ideas. Post below for points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.join` to do the filtering without changing the DataFrame.

```
df[df['letters'].str.join('') == 'A']
```

Comment: As one doesn't have to change the DataFrame, I will have to go with this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you thought the contents of letters were strings, could you convert the column of lists to strings? something like this:

```
df['letters'] = df['letters'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))
```

Then proceed to filter like you normally would